# Laravel Dompdf two column Layout

Tags: dompdf

I am not getting pdf content in column wise. What i want is to show the content in two column layout using dompdf laravel.The HTML which i am using is working fine in first page only not on all pages.

Comment: Please add your html and any css files to your question, it's not possible to help without them. Please read the help section on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML and CSS it's hard to diagnose the problem, but it might be if your column has a row which spans a page break.

In the [Limitations][1] section of the readme it says

> Table cells are not pageable, meaning a table row must fit on a single
>   page.

Make sure your table cells are on one page.

Comment: Hello thanks, That problem is solved. Actually problem was column count was not working with pdf so Column tag help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for pdf

```
.row{ clear: both; }
.col-lg-1 {width:8%;  float:left;}
.col-lg-2 {width:16%; float:left;}
.col-lg-3 {width:25%; float:left;}
.col-lg-4 {width:33%; float:left;}
.col-lg-5 {width:42%; float:left;}
.col-lg-6 {width:50%; float:left;}
.col-lg-7 {width:58%; float:left;}
.col-lg-8 {width:66%; float:left;}
.col-lg-9 {width:75%; float:left;}
.col-lg-10{width:83%; float:left;}
.col-lg-11{width:92%; float:left;}
.col-lg-12{width:100%; float:left;}
```